# Cinnamon notifications applet doesn't show history

Tags: linux-mint, chrome, cinnamon, notifications

In case of multiple notifications from the same site (pushed by Chrome browser) Notification applet in tray shows only last one.

E.g. using this demo https://gauntface.github.io/simple-push-demo/
I pushed 3 notifications, but in tray I see only the last one.

At the same time system notifications pushed by notify-send tool:

> /usr/bin/notify-send "hello"

showed as expected, every notification is in the list.

Is there a way to prevent notification overriding?

Answer (score 0):

It seems each notification must have unique id, otherwise it will be overwritten.
All notifications are visible after replacing static id to random:

```
chrome.notifications.create(Math.random().toString(36).substring(7), {
                type:'basic',
                iconUrl:'img.png',
                title: 'title',
                message: 'text'
            });
```